# Run Activity in other tab. Pass parameters to it

Tags: android, parameters, android-activity, tabs, bundle

Hello I have TabActivity application with two tabs. One activity get from bundle in OnCreate() method some default patameter and execute logic. On another activity view I have some control which send parameter to first activity with other value. But first activity opens separately without tabs! Ok. Also I can programmatically change current tab, but in this case how to get bundle object? OnStart and onResume callbacks does not have Bundle object.

I can save this parameter in Preferences when I press control, then programmatically change tab an get this parameter from Preferences in other activity. But I think it is wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You can call your own tab activity again like that

```
Intent theIntent = new Intent(this, TabActivity.class); 
theIntent.putExtra("targetTab", 3);
startActivity(theIntent);
```

and to pass data or parameter you can create singleton java class and pass your data to which activity you want.

Comment: I do not have any problems with start activity. I have a problem with start activity in a tab again. If I call startActivity(intent) activity opens as new window without tabs. I need restart activity and go to another tab.

Comment: you should call the activity with extends TabActivity.

Comment: Ok. Start my MainActivity extends TabActivity. onNewIntent() method of MainActivity called, all tabs already exists. How I can pass intent to activity in existing tab? Delete all tabs and recreate it again? Can I get particular tab and pass intent to it? Thanks.

Comment: In other words I need change existing tab content.

Comment: I had same problem. I have call my tab activity using intent and send a parameter named targetTab, then when my main tab activity runs i get value from intent and check which tab i should go, like that:   tabHost.setCurrentTab(targetTab); . Finally you can open witch tab you want by using this. To pass parameter i have create a singleton java class and set my attributes. Then i can get my class from any activity i want like that: MySingletonClass.getInstance().getMyAttribute();

Comment: cagryInside, thanks for reply. Singleton and preferences and other holders seems to me not good way. But if I will find nothing I will use this approach.

Comment: If you want to do some calculations you can override onPause and onResume in tab activity.